# Is there a way using CSS Zen coding on non css file

Tags: compass-sass, sass, emmet

I currently use notepad++, coda and espresso. I can't find a way to use the css zen coding on non css file for example on html file or scss for compass.

I would like to use zen coding for compass since it's much faster to type bgc for background-color instead of typing the whole word. It works on css files but not any other way.

the question is: how to enforce css zen coding, so it doesn't xpand with html < >

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For expresso I found the answer, and I think it's the same for any editor just go to in espresso toolbar view->language->css.
It must be the same for the others ;)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think you can hack the code of the plugin a little bit to get the result that you want.

Assuming you get your Zen CSS plugin from [here](http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/downloads/list), you can go to Zen Coding.js and modify code on line 26 to add extra extensions that you need.  This is just a guess, but generally you do something along those lines.  Good luck!

Comment: I tried, its pretty hard... for notepad++ is a python file I think, for espresso sugar its some xml and other bunch of code, I'm pretty sure there was someone way before me that have though about this and came up with a solution.

Answer (score 1):

In Notepad++, Go to Settings -> Style Configurator

Select CSS in the Languages list. In the user ext. text box, type "scss" or any other extension you would want the Zen Coding plugin to work with.

Note: This method also formats your scss as css which is great for normal scss files but might be ugly for partials.

Hope this helps!